# Getting simple access to google plus profile information

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I want to use the 'plus.people.get' API call from the Google Plus API, without a user login. Similar to what the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get) is doing.

I know that I will need to register my application and provide the client id and cleant secret, but I can not figure out on how to call the API. All examples I found explain how to do user login..

Thanks in advance for any links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For un-authenticated access to the API functions you will need an API-Key. Client ID/Secret are only necessary for OAuth.

If you do a request on the API explorer it will display a URL like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/<userid>?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

If you are using simple HTTP requests to retrieve data you just have to replace `{YOUR_API_KEY}` accordingly.

If you are using any of the client libraries, they all have methods to set the API Key, which will then be appended to all calls automatically.

You can get an API Key similar to how you get Client ID/Secret from the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).  Just look for "Your Project" -> APIs & Auth -> Credentials and use "Create new key" there, if one hasn't been created automatically already.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are there any examples on how to do this from java?  preferably with some library?

Comment: There is a client library for Java https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/ (you will have to check the docs, there are some samples there, but not sure how useful they are)

Comment: Thanks. I did dig deeper now and did find a sample that pointed me in the right direction. In the end, it is rather easy to do

Comment: @Scarygami I don't provide key in my url and still getting list of people, why do we need provide api_key?